# How we can pass an array to a method using Groovy Script TestStep in SoapUI Pro?

Tags: testing, groovy, scripting, automation, soapui

I'm new to **Groovy Script with SoapUI**. I have to pass an array to a method and modify the values and then print them in the log. For that, I have written the following script. But its not working as expected.

```
String [] countries = new String[5];
void ReuseArray(String[] regions){};

countries[0] = "India";
countries[1] = "Singapore";
countries[2] = "Indonesia";
countries[3] = "Japan";
countries[4] = "Thailand";

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    log.info("Country :" + countries[i]);
}

ReuseArray(countries);

void ReuseArrayData(String[] regions)
{
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        log.info("Method :" + regions[i]);
    }
}
```

The above script produces the following output:

Thu Jul 10 19:08:13 IST 2014:INFO:Welcome 
Thu Jul 10 19:08:13 IST 2014:INFO:Country :India 
Thu Jul 10 19:08:13 IST 2014:INFO:Country :Singapore 
Thu Jul 10 19:08:13 IST 2014:INFO:Country :Indonesia 
Thu Jul 10 19:08:13 IST 2014:INFO:Country :Japan 
Thu Jul 10 19:08:13 IST 2014:INFO:Country :Thailand

Please correct me If I'm wrong.

Comment: What is the output you are expecting from the script?

Comment: As per the above script, it should show the 5 countries names list but it is not displaying...

Comment: It appears that this has nothing to do with SoapUI, this is only a Groovy problem? Further, your code is pure Java, and not even Groovy ... which is fine, since Groovy is 99% source compatible with Groovy. Your script will **not** produce the `Welcome` log info message, but it will produce the other five `Country` messages. Your method `ReuseArrayData()` is never used. I do not see what the problem is.

Comment: So can't we use argument methods in Groovy script with SoapUI?

Answer (score 3):

I have found the correct answer for my question after identified the bug. Here's the code.

```
log.info("Welcome ")
String [] countries = new String[5];

countries[0] = "India";
countries[1] = "Singapore";
countries[2] = "Indonesia";
countries[3] = "Japan";
countries[4] = "Thailand";

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    log.info("Country :" + countries[i]);
}

ReuseArrayData(countries);

void ReuseArrayData(String[] regions)
{
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        log.info("Method :" + regions[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays as parameters to functions in groovy/Java, but as for your code is concerned seems to be ReuseArray does not have any definition and ReuseArrayData is never been called.